# MAAS 1.7 How to Deploy utopic images

Tags: boot, juju, maas, 14.10

Installed MAAS 1.7 and successfully deployed several Trusty images; however, cannot deploy any utopic images. Added utopic repository by following http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/bootsources.html, and my boot source, now, looks like the following:

```
$ maas maas17 boot-sources read $CLUSTER_UUID
[
    {
        "url": "http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/daily/", 
        "keyring_data": "", 
        "resource_uri": "/MAAS/api/1.0/boot-sources/1/", 
        "keyring_filename": "/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg", 
        "id": 1
    }
]
```

During deployment, where utopic image is chosen, I get the following:

```
...
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-path/ip-10.0.0.17:3260-iscsi-iqn.2004-05.com.ubuntu:maas:ephemeral-ubuntu-amd64-generic-utopic-daily-lun-1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-8ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) [ 99.600706] random: nonblocking pool is intialized
```

Any thoughts as how to get an utopic image deployed?
Cheers,

Edit 1: Seems to be a known problem https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1391354
Edit 2: For now, the work around is NOT to deploy with "Use the fast installer" option.