# How to Install Juno Openstack

Tags: juju, 14.10, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

Trying to get Juno going using MAAS and JUJU; however, it seems that there are no viable alternatives. Tried the following:
1- Upgraded to 14.10 and did a fresh MAAS and JUJU install; however, utopic images are not bootable. See [MAAS 1.7 How to Deploy utopic images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551085/maas-1-7-how-to-deploy-utopic-images)
2- Tried and still am trying openstack-install; however, I am not sure if this is the correct path, as openstack-install is not avaiable on 14.10, which from my understating is what's needed to get Juno. I tried the old instructions of openstack-install on 14.04, which timed out during boot image download, and am trying the new instructions on 14.04. (Though not sure if it is Juno capable.)

So any ideas as how to get Juno going?
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

If you have MAAS 1.7 and juju already installed, you can go ahead and install Landscape and try out the OpenStack Autopilot:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

This guide includes instructions on how to install MAAS too, which you seem to already have. Just make sure you have the right versions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. So, there are no free solutions? Looks as though Landscape is not free https://landscape.canonical.com/trial-registration

Comment: @user281985 landscape is free up to 10 seats which is plenty to get openstack deployed

Comment: So, 10 seats do not have the 30 days time limit, i.e., I can run them indefinitely?

Comment: @user281985 Correct!

Comment: Landscape has "10+10" seats, that is, 10 seats for bare metal machines, and 10 seats for virtual machines, which include containers.